# Copy image selected image to another external storage but get error here this is the code...in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

> image selection from gallery
>
> Intent for image selection:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");//for only image selection
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

                    }
```

Create external storage:

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream;


mFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Yourfoldername");//create external storage directory
                if (!mFolder.exists()) {
                    mFolder.mkdirs();
                    mFolder.setExecutable(true);
                    mFolder.setReadable(true);
                    mFolder.setWritable(true);
                } //set permission also
```

> Result of intent data:

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE){
                    fileUri = data.getData();
                    String s = getPath(fileUri);//getpath from function
                    Log.i(getClass().getName(), "fileUri" + fileUri);
                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hii",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        copyFile(s, mFolder + IMG_FILE_NAME+ ".jpg");//copy the image to selected folder
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    Log.i(getClass().getName(), String.valueOf(fileUri));
                }
            }
        }
```

> Copy the image from gallery to external storage, copy.java:

```
public void copyFile(String selectedImagePath, String string) throws IOException {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(selectedImagePath);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(string);

            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            Toast customToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
            customToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Image Transferred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            customToast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            customToast.show();
        }
     public String getPath(Uri uri) {
         String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
         Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
         startManagingCursor(cursor);
         int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         return cursor.getString(column_index);
     }// for get the path of image
    }
```

> Getting the same error, I tried lot of code and couldn't fix this error.

![getting  error like this][1]

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfGyQ.png

Comment: did you add **permissions** to `manifest.xml`.

Comment: yes add permission to manifest.xml .

Comment: Your error is related to the onActivityResult, where is your setResult code?

Comment: i don't know about where to store the set Result code give me solution please thanks....@ Marcos Vasconcelos

Comment: please give me solution please .....#androidstudio

Comment: Your error is at: Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
         startManagingCursor(cursor);

Comment: The thumbnail seens to be correct

Comment: Thanks Sir@Marcos Vasconcelos problem solved

Answer (score 0):

By your stacktrace img, your error is at:

```
Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null); 
startManagingCursor(cursor); // << Here
```

The thumbnail seens to be correct